# Unable to run Bash 5 from launchd

Tags: catalina, bash, launchd

I have the following launchd agent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>bash-check</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/spark/tmp/bash-check</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/laktak/bash-check.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

With the following script `bash-check`:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

type bash
bash --version
```

I cannot get it to use Bash 5 (`/usr/local/bin/bash`), the log from `launchctl start bash-check` is always:

```
bash is /bin/bash
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: What is the output of running `echo $PATH` in Terminal.app?

Comment: @NimeshNeema in what way would this influence the launchd agent? It does not use my environment. PATH includes `/usr/local/bin` in Terminal but not for the launchd agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script uses `type` to find the first instance of `bash` within `PATH` and then calls exactly that instance. So if `/bin` is before `/usr/local/bin` (or, more likely, `/usr/local/bin` isn't in `PATH`) the macOS version of `bash` is found and executed.

To check the version of the running shell use

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
```

instead.